# Python - string contains - giving error when using multiple criteria

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to Python and very much learning still.

I have a column that I want to add multiple selection criteria to, specifically where Marital Status is either Divorce, Separated, Widowed or Never-married.

The coding I have used is below - I get a syntax error when I have multiple options. The same code with just 'Divorce' it works perfectly fine.

What I am doing wrong please?

```
adult_data_list = adult_data[(adult_data['age'] > 50) & 
                             (adult_data['Marital_status'].str.contains('Divorce', 'Separated', 'Widowed', 'Never-married'))
                            ]
```

Comment: Is `adult_data['Marital_status']` a string, or is it an object with a string attribute called `str` (which, if so, is confusing because `str` is the name of the string *type*)?

Comment: _I get a syntax error when I have multiple options_ Please show us the full error.

Comment: `str.contains()` can only have one pattern argument. If you want to test multiple strings, use a regular expression with `|` for alternation.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I've just checked and it's an object. This is a provided dataset rather than one I've created. Is the solution to change marital_status to a string? Or is there another way to deal with the scenario?

Comment: It seems like you need to read a good Pandas tutorial.

Comment: @John Gordon - the error is - 
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'RegexFlag'

Comment: So it's a TypeError, not a SyntaxError as you said before?

Comment: I've sorted it now using the | as suggested by @Barmar. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Contains just checks if one string is contained within the value. You should use a regular expression instead. For example:

```
import re
status_reg = re.compile('(Divorce|Separated|Widowed|Never-married)')
adult_data_list = adult_data[(adult_data['age'] > 50 &
                             (adult_data['Marital_status'].apply(status_reg.search))
                            ]
```

You can adjust the regex accordingly.
Note that it'll return true for any of the martial statuses in the regex.